# animate css background-size cover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a background image attached to a container div like so.

```
#container {background: url('https://path/to/my.com/img.jpg') no-repeat center 0px fixed; 
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                     -moz-background-size: cover;
                         -o-background-size: cover;
                                background-size: cover;}
```

How can i animate this using jQuery?

```
var val_x = 120;
$('#container').stop().animate({ 'background-position-x' :val_x}, 500);
```

Comment: Note: 1) Background-`size` and -`position` are different properties. 2 ) Firefox doesn't understand background-position-`x` and -`y`.

Comment: thank you @MartinErnst i guess i would somehow need to maintain the aspect ratio of `background-size:cover` while changing position?

Comment: No, size and position are independant, they don't affect each other. But you have the problem that both takes two values, position the x and y, size the width and height. jQuery alone can only animate one value a time, so try [search for a plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/animation/) that does the job.

Comment: the cover property essentially like setting the height of the background to 100%. try background-size auto 100%; auto being the x-axis, and 100% being the y-axis